# Why do I get Element not interactable without browser.getCurrentUrl in protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have this piece of code:

```
const elem = element(by.xpath(selector));
browser.getCurrentUrl();
browser.wait(() => elem.clear().getText().then(text => text === ''), timeout, `Waiting for element '${selector}' to be cleared timed out`);
```

It works fine. But if I remove browser.getCurrentUrl(), it fails.

```
const elem = element(by.xpath(selector));
browser.wait(() => elem.clear().getText().then(text => text === ''), timeout, `Waiting for element '${selector}' to be cleared timed out`);
```

Here is part of the error:

```
- Failed: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
    (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.78)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.0-98-generic x86_64)
    (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.78)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.0-98-generic x86_64)
    at WebDriverError (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
    at InvalidElementStateError (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:124:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
    From: Task: WebElement.clear()
    at Driver.schedule (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
    at WebElement.schedule_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2010:25)
    at WebElement.clear (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2351:17)
    at actionFn (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:89:44)
    at Array.map (native)
    at actionResults.getWebElements.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:461:65)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
    at asyncRun (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)Error
```

Why am I getting this?

What is the correct way to proceed? I do not want to ask for the current URL if I don't need it. I also want to understand the problem.

Thank you

Comment: It's probably a timing issue that no longer occurs due to the delay produced by `browser.getCurrentUrl()`. Note that your need to call `.getAttribute('value')` to get the text from an `<input>`. To solve your issue, wait for the element to be interractable or until there's exception.

Comment: getText does the same thing. I want to clear the input and then fill it with my value. I don't care about it's value.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to thank you for your input :D Also, I changed the code to be more explicit. Here are the with and without getCurrentUrl with logging. https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/1GGku2i5pKa2RvQVj0F~wQ